# Left outer join in LINQ is showing exception

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting the following exception:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-
>   nullable value type.

Below is my LINQ Statement where QuestionId is the primary key in my table:

```
var questionViewsData =
      from questionViews in objDc.SC_QuestionsViews
      join questions in objDc.SC_Questions
      on questionViews.QuestionId equals questions.QuestionId into qs
      from questions in qs.DefaultIfEmpty()
      where questionViews.CreatedDate.Date == new DateTime(2010, 4,27)
      select new 
      {
          Selected =(questions == null ?-1:questions.QuestionId),
          QuestioinTitle = questions.Title,
          VotesCount = questions.VotesCount 
      };
```

Comment: Please use appropriate logging to find out what SQL is being generated, and edit the question with that - it'll make it much easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
where questionViews.CreatedDate.Date == new DateTime(2010, 4,27)
```

to

```
where questionViews.CreatedDate == new DateTime(2010, 4, 27)
```

as a test you could run

```
where questionViews.CreatedDate > new DateTime(2010, 4, 26)
```

N.B. If I include .Date in a LinqPad c# statement I receive the following error message and removing .Date allows the statement to run.

```
System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no
extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, try running it with this:

```
select new 
      {
          Selected = questions.QuestionId,
          QuestioinTitle = questions.Title,
          VotesCount = questions.VotesCount 
      };
```

What do you get?